# Parameter 'input' is required by using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to using google earth engine. Exploring forums I found a script that is very useful to me, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Error: Error in map(ID=20201020T135119_20201020T135116_T21KVQ): 
String.replace: Parameter 'input' is required.
```

What is the mistake?

Here is the link: [https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d322c73d4efc6c12203133bf025c04d[enter](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d322c73d4efc6c12203133bf025c04d%5Benter) link description here][1](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d322c73d4efc6c12203133bf025c04d)

```
var Paraguay = ee.FeatureCollection("users/marcelos/Poligonos_segundo_informe_1-polygon")

Map.centerObject(Paraguay)
Map.addLayer(Paraguay)

var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterDate('2020-10-20', '2020-10-30')
  .filterBounds(Paraguay)
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 20)

var maskcloud = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1))
}

var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
}

var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud)
  .map(NDVI)

var ts = NDVIcol.map(calculateFarmersNDVI)

function calculateFarmersNDVI(image) {
  var properties = ee.Dictionary(
    Paraguay.iterate(function(region, acc) {
      return ee.Dictionary(acc)
        .combine(
          ndviForArea(image, ee.Feature(region))
        )
    }, ee.Dictionary())
  )
  return ee.Feature(null, properties
    .set('Year', image.date().get('year'))
    .set('Month', image.date().get('month'))
    .set('Day', image.date().get('day'))
  )
}

function ndviForArea(image, region) {
  var ndvi = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: region.geometry(),
    scale: 30
  }).get('NDVI')
  // Not all characters are valid property names in EE
  // dictionaries. Replace them with _
  var farmers = region.getString('Farmers')
    .replace('\\W', '_', 'g')

  // There might be images without any value for the region.
  // ee.Dictionary.set() must have a non-null value.
  // The If() statement replaces null with an empty string.
  var ndviOrBlank = ee.Algorithms.If(ndvi, ndvi, '')
  return ee.Dictionary().set(farmers, ndviOrBlank)
}

var listOfFarmers = ee.List(Paraguay.aggregate_array('Farmers'))
  .map(function (farmers) { 
    return ee.String(farmers).replace('\\W', '_', 'g')
  })
ee.List(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
  .cat(listOfFarmers)  
  // We want to provide toDrive() selectors, to
  // get the CSV columns ordered. This must be a 
  // client-side object though, so we need to call
  // evaluate() on it before using it.
  .evaluate(function (selectors) {
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: ts,
      description: 'NDVI_test4',
      fileFormat: 'CSV',
      selectors: selectors
    })    
  })
```

Comment: I reproduced the error, but solved adding the property `Farmers` to the Features inside the fake FeatureCollection I made for testing (you didn't share `Paraguay`)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I have added the "Farmers" property to my featurecollection (https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/marcelos/Poligonos_segundo_informe_1-polygon), but I still keep getting the same error "map error parameter input is required" . I don't know what I could be doing wrong. With this code what I'm looking for is to export the NDVI values ​​of all the polygons that my featurecollection contains.